# Please, how can I find an algorithm which checks for inverting 2 consecutive characters

Tags: c

Please how can I check for the second condition (using an algorithm instead because I'm
expecting other passwords, it means that I need to check for all of them, and basically it's
impossible to know the passwords which will be entered, so I need an algorithm (inverting 2
consecutive characters)which does this task( for instance passwords might: (abcdefg),
(hhgfts543),(GFYS!-rii)).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main (void) {
char pass[50];
char validPass[50]="abc123";
printf("Your password: ");
scanf("%s", pass); // the expected password doesn't contain a space
if (strcmp(pass, validPas)==0) {
    printf("Password match...!");
}
else if (strcmp(pass, "bac123")==0 ||
         strcmp(pass, "acb123")==0 ||
         strcmp(pass, "ab1c23")==0 ||
         strcmp(pass, "abc213")==0 ||
         strcmp(pass, "abc123")==0 ||) {

  //An algorithm which checks for inverting 2 consecutive characters

printf("CLOSE TO GUESSINGING THE PASSWORD !");
}
else 
printf("WRONG PASSWORD !");
return 0; 
}
```

Comment: The algorithm to invert 2 things is called a swap, it's a great beginner exercise

Comment: Wouldn't the last be `strcmp(pass, "abc132")==0 ||)`?

Comment: Why not consider `size_t len = strlen(pass);` and then loop `for (size_t i = 1; i < len; i++) { /* make a copy of pass; swap passcpy[i-1] passcpy[i] & compare */ }`

Comment: It seems like if they have all the correct letters, but the wrong order, you want to give them some highly secure encouragement.  Simplest way to do that would be to compute a histogram of letter frequencies for the password, and do the same when they guess.  If the histogram matches but the password is incorrect, then tell them they're very close to breaking into the system.  Alternatively, they could instead attack your program with a buffer overflow caused by your unsafe use of `scanf`.

Comment: @paddy brings up a good point. What are you trying to accomplish? I took it to be you want to prevent a user from entering the same password as an update with only two characters swapped. If something else -- then a simple swap isn't what you want. (I guess the `"CLOSE TO GUESSINGING THE PASSWORD !"` is a hint that it is the latter)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use a method like this:

```
    // ALT: declare variable as false
    for (int i = 0; i<s.Length-1; i++) /*loop through the characters except the last 
                                       (we want to swap each character with the next one)*/ 
    {
        if (s.Substring(0, i) /*unchanged first part*/ 
           + s[i + 1] + s[i] /*swapped characters*/ 
           + s.Substring(i + 2, s.Length - i - 2) /*rest of the string*/ 
           == test) 
        {
            return true; // ALT: variable to true
        }
    }
    return false; // remove in ALT
```

Sorry for not using c. The point should come across. 
You could alternatively declare a first variable as false and only change it to true if the condition is met. 
(marked as "ALT") 
I hope you understand my intention and are able to use my input for the solution of your problem.